# Setting RecyclerView scrolling position on Android

Tags: java, android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Implementing Flexible Space pattern (the one with the collapse toolbar) using [this tutorial](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

Everything works fine, except for a feature I'm trying to achieve which doesn't work yet: I want to be able to expand or shrink the ImageView header just like in the Contacts screen on Lollipop, where the user is able to expand or shrink the image of the contact.

Right now after the activity starts, the image is at it's full size, which is the size of the `AppBar` (it's size is 0 since I set it programmatically).

I'd like to start with the `image view / appbar` (whatever you're looking at) minimized, i.e. not only be able to scroll down (as in the tutorial, so image size is at it's full size at the beginning but then shrinks) but to be able to scroll up the layout in order to reveal more of the image header as well.
Right now it's impossible, as the activity starts with the `image / appbar` at their full size, so I can't expand them anymore.

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.activity_profile_bottom_recyclerview);

    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    if(mAdapter == null){
        mAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(this, user, inEditMode);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Length of adapter is 4 items, which doesn't even takes half screen.
That's my xml layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_profile"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" // set programatically
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="32dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/header"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activity_profile_bottom_recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" /> 

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <include          
        layout="@layout/navigation_view"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Why doesn't `scrollToPosition` works? Maybe since I got only 4 items (that's what the adapter's item count would retrieve)? Tried also `scrollToPositionWithOffset`.

Note: If I scroll manually up, the RecyclerView goes up, it just won't work through code.

I'm also opened to hear other ways to achieve what I want except scrolling programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try adding more items and using The following code:

```
recycleView.scrollTo(int x, int y)
```

or

```
recycleView.scrollTo(int x, int y)
```

or

```
recycleView.scrollToPosition(int position)
```

Comment: RecyclerView does not support scrolling to an absolute position.

Answer (score -1):

For the scrolling problem you need to put the Recycler view in a ScrollView.